# Default vector constructor with a unique_ptr and thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++14, unique-ptr

What is the right way to call teh default vector contructor that creates 'n' elements of `std::unique_ptr`'s holding threads.

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::thread>> thr_grp(5, std::move(std::make_unique<std::thread>(std::thread(), threadWorker)));
```

or

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::thread>> thr_grp(5, std::move(std::unique_ptr<std::thread>(new std::thread(threadWorker))));
```

or either with out the `std::move` semantic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This cannot be done in this way because fill [constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) of the `std::vector` make copies of the specified parameter and the `std::unique_ptr` has deleted copy constructor.

You can [emplace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) elements into a default constructed `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::thread>>` like the following example does:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

void threadWorker() {
    std::cout << "I'm thread: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::thread>> thr_grp;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        thr_grp.emplace_back(std::make_unique<std::thread>(threadWorker));

    for(auto& e : thr_grp)
        e->join();
    return 0;
}
```

Another approach is to construct and fill your `std::vector` with default constructed values and assign the values later:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::thread>> thr_grp(5);
for(auto& e : thr_grp)
    e = std::make_unique<std::thread>(threadWorker);
```

The code above will use move semantics, you don't have to explicitly indicate it with `std::move`.

Comment: I usually prefer the second one